# How to use ConfirmPopup (p-confirmpopup) with HTML/component instead of string message

Tags: angular, primeng

I need a dialog that is displayed relatively to its target to display a complex set of properties about objects on the screen. PrimeNG ConfirmPopup is displayed relatively to its target but it accepts only a string message.

Is there any way to pass HTML to ConfirmPopup? Or is there a better PrimeNT component for this purpose? It is important that the dialog is displayed relatively to its target.

I tried to pass HTML tags in the string but the string is HTML escaped. I tried to look in the PrimeNG ConfirmPopup code but I wasn't able to find where they escape the message.

I was thinking of passing a standard string to the popup and then search for it and replace it, but it seem too hacky.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way directly adding html in primeng confirm box.

```
  dropDatabase(event: Event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
    event.preventDefault();
    this.confirmation.confirm({
      key: 'confirm-drop-database',
      message: 'Are you sure to remove all data?',
      accept: () => { this._dropDatabase(); },
    });
    console.log(this.confirm.nativeElement);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.confirm.nativeElement.querySelector('.ui-confirmdialog-message').innerHTML ="<h1> test</h1>";
    }, 0);
  }
```

Full working example in below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-confirmdialog-default-button-vttzdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts